# Почему когда я добавляю иконку в QListView, то у меня прога останавливается?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, drag-n-drop, qlistview

У меня все работало норм, но как только я добавил туда иконку, то у меня прога завершается и выдаёт ошибку.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class DemoWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, widgets, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.widgets = widgets
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('DemoWidget {background-color: #D98C00;}')

        self.movingButton = None
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        for name in self.widgets:
            mimeData = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')
            if name in str(mimeData, 'utf-8').replace('\x00', ''):
                if name == 'pushButton':
                    widget = QPushButton()
                elif name == 'label':
                    widget = QLabel()
                    widget.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: #B5FE83;}')
                elif name == 'lineEdit':
                    widget = QLineEdit()
                elif name == 'radibutton':
                    widget = QRadioButton()
                widget.setParent(self)
                widget.setText(name)
            widget.move(event.pos())
            widget.show()
            widget.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and \
              event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.movingButton = source
            self.startPos = event.pos()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.movingButton:
            self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and self.movingButton:
            self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
            self.movingButton = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.l_view = QtWidgets.QListView(self)
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.l_view.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.l_view.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.l_view.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.l_view.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.l_view.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)

        self.widgets = [
            'pushButton',
            'lineEdit',
            'label',
            'radibutton',
        ]

        self.demoWidget = DemoWidget(self.widgets, self)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.demoWidget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.l_view, 1)
        lay.addLayout(vlay, 5)

        for name in self.widgets:
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(QIcon('uuuu.ico'), f"{name}")
            self.l_view.model().appendRow(it)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Вот ошибка :**

> if name in str(mimeData, 'utf-8').replace('\x00', ''):
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 67: invalid start byte

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class DemoWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, widgets, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.widgets = widgets
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('DemoWidget {background-color: #D98C00;}')
        self.movingButton = None
        
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        for name in self.widgets:
            mimeData = event.mimeData().data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist')
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            _mimeData = mimeData.split('\n')[-1]
            mimeData = str(_mimeData, 'utf-8', errors='ignore').replace('\x00', '')
            if name in mimeData:
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                if name == 'pushButton':
                    widget = QPushButton()
# установите свое изображение ----------> vvvvvvv            
                    widget.setIcon(QIcon("cat.jpg"))                    # +++
                    widget.setIconSize(QSize(100, 75))                  # +++ 
                elif name == 'label':
                    widget = QLabel()
                    widget.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background-color: #B5FE83;}')
                elif name == 'lineEdit':
                    widget = QLineEdit()
                elif name == 'radibutton':
                    widget = QRadioButton()
                widget.setParent(self)
                widget.setText(name)

# --------> >>>>             
                widget.move(event.pos())
                widget.show()
                widget.installEventFilter(self)
                break                                                    # +++
# --------> >>>>                

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and \
              event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.movingButton = source
            self.startPos = event.pos()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.movingButton:
            self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and self.movingButton:
            self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
            self.movingButton = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.l_view = QtWidgets.QListView(self)
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.l_view.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.l_view.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.l_view.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.l_view.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.l_view.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)

        self.widgets = [
            'pushButton',
            'lineEdit',
            'label',
            'radibutton',
        ]

        self.demoWidget = DemoWidget(self.widgets, self)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.demoWidget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.l_view, 1)
        lay.addLayout(vlay, 5)

        for name in self.widgets:
            item = QListWidgetItem()
#            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(QIcon('uuuu.ico'), f"{name}")
# установите свое изображение ------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvv
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(QIcon('hand_icon.ico'), f"{name}")
            self.l_view.model().appendRow(it)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо ты просто лучший @S. Nick